# Why do I have both PHPSESSID and sec_session_id?

Tags: php, session, cookies, https

I have SSL enabled site wide and want to use a secure session using HTTPS.  I have two session cookies, PHPSESSID and sec_session_id.  I cant figure out why the browsers are showing the PHPSESSID as not being "HTTP only" and not "secure", while the sec_session_id is "HTTP only" and is "secure".  When I do session_regenerate_id(), only the PHPSESSID is changed.  Why are there two cookies?  Why is only the unsecured cookie regenerated?  What can I do?  Here is my php.ini;

```
session.cookie_httponly = 1;
session.use_only_cookies = 1;
session.cookie_secure = 1;
```

and my php

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: Let me guess: You didn't configure that server, right? And also you only have showed one php.ini. Where is the other php.ini? So please contact your support personnel, most likely the sysadmin of that computer. If you used some software package to do the configuration for you, please contact the vendor of that software package for your support options.

Comment: And what's wrong with having two cookies? I don't understand your questions, they all sound like that you're confronted with two cookies you have no clue where they come from and as both seem to be related but have differences you question each of those differences. But please let us all know per each difference what your own understanding of those are and to which reference you relate to with your understandings. Thanks.

Comment: And you should write who tells you that those are HTTP only and secure (I would assume your browser does, but it doesn't hurt if you share more details about that as well)

Comment: Found the answer for my problem.  Just clear the browser cache.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an  handling error with the OPs internet browser (HTTP HTML client).